# Dockerfile for angular development not updating node_modules

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using the following Dockerfile for development of an Angular project:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /code
COPY package*.json /code/
RUN npm ci --quiet
```

It gets started with `docker compose`. My code folder is mounted as a volume so the development server inside the container detects changes when editing and keeps live updates going:

```
version: "3"

services:
  ui:
    build: ./PathOnHostWithProjectRepo
    command: sh -c "npm start"
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    volumes:
      - ./PathOnHostWithProjectRepo:/code
      - node_modules:/code/node_modules

volumes:
  node_modules:
```

`node_modules` gets created when the image is created and, to my understanding, would only update if my `package.json` is changed. However, today I updated `package.json` with a new dependency and it is not being installed inside of the volume. I have tried everything I can think of. `docker compose down`, `docker system prune -a -f`, and rebuilding. Every time the container starts there is an error that it cannot find the new dependency added. If I step into the container and inspect the `node_modules` folder the library isn't there. It is present on my host machine if I run `npm install` locally without Docker, so I know the package and imports must be correct.

Answer (score 1):

With this setup your `node_modules` will *never* be updated.  Docker will completely ignore any changes in your `package.json` file.  You've told it that directory contains user data that must not be modified.

For the setup you show you don't need Docker at all.  It's straightforward to [install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and OS package managers like Debian/Ubuntu APT or MacOS Homebrew generally have a prepackaged version.  If you use Node directly then you won't have problems like this; everything will work normally.

If you must use Docker here, the most straightforward thing to do is to make sure all of your application code is in a subdirectory; then you can mount only the subdirectory containing the code and leave the image's `node_volumes` directory intact.

```bash
$ ls -F
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
node_modules/
package.json
package-lock.json
src/
```

```bash
# Dockerfile
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /code
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY src/ ./src/
# RUN npm build
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  ui:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/code/src
```

Mounting only the `src` subdirectory avoids the trouble of storing `node_modules` in a named volume (or an anonymous one).  If you change your `package.json` file you will need to re-run `docker-compose build`, but since you're directly using the library tree in your image then this will in fact get updated.

If you're going to deploy this image somewhere, remember to delete the `volumes:` block during your local integration testing so that you're actually running the image you're going to deploy, and not a hybrid of an image and your potentially-modified local code.

Comment: Docker because I actually have 3 containers in my compose file - The Angular front end, a Web API, and a database. I omitted them for brevity in my question. I was trying to do this: https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-an-angular-app/ just mounting the volumes in the docker compose file instead of with `docker run`. Seems to be the same thing.

Comment: You can still use a non-Docker development environment, proxying to a Docker-hosted backend or database in the same way you would if those backend components were running directly on the host.